# How to setup the sub query to get parent and related list data

Tags: soql, servicecloud, sales-cloud

`BOG_Committee_w_Membership__c` has a lookup field to `BOG_Committee__c`.

I need the fields

1) `BOG_Committee__r.Name, BOG_Committee__r.Official_1__r.FirstName, BOG_Committee__r.Role_1__c, BOG_Membership__r.ORG__c`  from `BOG_Committee_w_Membership__c`

2) and `id, Name` from `BOG_Committee__c`.

3) and I need to have it `WHERE BOG_Committee__r.Name = '1 The Executive'`.

How to setup the query and sub query to get the results?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Id` is the actual lookup field `BOG_Committee__c` and you already have listed the `Name` field - `BOG_Committee__r.Name`.

So you pretty much need to write the `SELECT` phrase:

`SELECT BOG_Committee__c, BOG_Committee__r.Name, BOG_Committee__r.Official_1__r.FirstName, BOG_Committee__r.Role_1__c, BOG_Membership__r.ORG__c FROM BOG_Committee_w_Membership__c WHERE BOG_Committee__r.Name = '1 The Executive'`.

Comment: It only returns 3 records. There are a lot more records in BOG_Committee_w_Membership__c  that have the BOG_Committee__r.Name = '1 The Executive'. What am I missing?

Comment: Double check spelling in the record name as well as your security model and your profile settings. It might be just a typo in the name, or it could be that you don't have access to the rest of the records.